# Mui pro component is included under premium licence?

Tags: material-ui

We intend to purchase a MUI licence key for data grid at https://mui.com/x/introduction/licensing/#premium-plan.

We also need to use a date-range picker, which can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/x-date-pickers-pro. But I'm not sure if it will be included in the premium plan because the date-range selector is only available in the pro plan!

does anyone know is premium licence includes pro component of mui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be included:

> The Premium version contains all features from Pro, as well as
> features for analyzing large datasets. The features available on the
> initial release are row grouping and the ability to export to Excel
> files.

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/